# cordova build android - Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, cordova, build, phonegap

I just used cordova phonegap and I was very confused how to create an .apk file. when I run the command "cordova build android" I get an error message like this. Please help me!!!
[this is what i try to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQlmJ.png)

Comment: What's the question here? What have you done so far?

Comment: the question is how to build an .apk file in cordova phonegap? i have run "cordova build android" and i got an error like the image i post above.